# how to execute functions next to each other using Typescript and Promises

Tags: typescript, promise, ionic2

I have this function which is getting invoked on a button click and later this executed 2 different functions, Now I need to execute it one after other as some of the input for second function comes from previous one.

```
processPayment(){
      console.log("payment called", this.registrationList);
      this.registerLoading.present().then(() => {
        //function1
        this.sendRegistration().then(data => {
            this.registerLoading.dismiss();
            this.paymentLoading.present().then(() => {
          //function 2
                this.sendPayments().then (data => {
                    this.paymentLoading.dismiss();
                    this.nav.popToRoot();
                    this.doAlert("Event Registration & Payments successful");
                });
            });
        });
      });
  }
```

Function 1:

```
sendRegistration(){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        for(let registration of this.registrationList){ 
          //codes removed for simplification
          this.eventsService.postRegistration(eventRegistration)
          .then(data => {
              console.log("called", data);
              this.invoices.push(data.Invoice.Id);
            });
        }
    });
  }
```

Function 2:

```
sendPayments(){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
              //codes removed for simpplication
      });
    }
```

Though I can see that it seem to execute sequentially but first function is not ending at all so I cant see the second executing.

Comment: You say "first function is not ending at all". Does it mean that `console.log("called", data)` never happens? Could it be actually related to the function code, the `//codes removed for simplification` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use full power of promises called chaining:

```
processPayment(){
  console.log("payment called", this.registrationList);
  this.registerLoading.present().then(() => {
    //function1
    return this.sendRegistration()
  }).then(data => {
    this.registerLoading.dismiss();
    return this.paymentLoading.present()
  }).then(() => {
    //function 2
    return this.sendPayments()
  }).then(data => {
    this.paymentLoading.dismiss();
    this.nav.popToRoot();
    this.doAlert("Event Registration & Payments successful");
  });
}
```

But your real problem is you never resolve promise in sendRegistration, and in your case it's complicated because you need to wait until all this.postRegistration promises are done. It could be done using Promise.all() method that will wait until all promises will be done. I hope you will understand how it work from your example:

```
sendRegistration(){
    let allPostRegistrationPromises = [];
    for (let registration of this.registrationList) {
      //codes removed for simplification
      let promise = this.eventsService.postRegistration(eventRegistration)
        .then(data => {
          console.log("called", data);
          this.invoices.push(data.Invoice.Id);
          return data;
        });
      allPostRegistrationPromises.push(promise);
    }
    return Promise.all(allPostRegistrationPromises);
}
```

This code should work, but i didn't test it.

You really should read this great article, to understand how Promises work and their real power: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html